# selecting data from a pre made SQLite arabic database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite(s3db) database with arabic and english words and I placed the local in there as en_US and I am trying to get some arabic data from it but I can't I am getting symbols instead of letters what should I do, I searched for it found that I should work on encoding UTF-8 or..
but I didn't find any details and usefull info please need help,

My code is:

```
 public String getResult(int id)
    {
        String name = null;
        try
        {
            Cursor c = null;
            c = bdd.rawQuery("select Title from List where _id="+id, null);
            c.moveToFirst();            
            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));            
            c.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name; 
    }
```

I used a pre made SQLite database so I wrote the data into it from outside android see [link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

thanks.

***Edit:***

```
I inserted that:
            byte[] b;            
            b = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));            
            name=b.toString();
            name=new String(b,"UTF-8");
instead of:
            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));
```

So now I am getting question marks in black boxes, I checked to see if my database is UTF-8 encoded and yes it is so what's causing that I am really working on this since hours now any help?!!

***EDIT2***
SO my database is not utf-8 encoded the arabic words are written as ansi or iso.. and I tried to use:

```
name = new String(c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("Title")), "UTF-8");

           byte[] chars = name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
           String utf8 = new String(chars,"ISO-8859-1");
           name=utf8;
```

to transform their encoding to a readable encoding with android but that didn't work as I don't know which encoding to add anyone has an idea about that?

***EDit3:*** So basically I could solve this as I placed the arabic words in notepad++ as UTF-8 and pressed ansi so notepad transformed my words to utf-8 and then I can place them like that in my database and I retrieved data from it and it worked...

Comment: SQLite encodes strings in UTF-8, but this is of no concern when you're using the Android API; strings are unchanged after writing to and reading from the database. Show your code!

Comment: I am facing the same problem with Urdu characters but I am not using notepad++ because of JE SUIS CHARLIE Edition, I love my prophet more than anything, and the developer of notepat++ is a fool man if he don't care about our religion.

Answer (score 0):

Do not write to the databases in Android directly. You should use ContentProvider. There is a great library that you can easily use databases with ContentProviders with it. Here it is: https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen

If you use this, you can store whatever string you want without having an encoding problem.

Comment: thanks but I need another solution, I want to use a pre made database without contentproviders... @tasomaniac

Comment: @CL I placed the code above in the post and I used a pre made sqlite database and I linked it to my app and took the words from it the english words worked perfectly but the arabic words appeared as symbols